# 2.3.5 - New Orders with approved payment are created as 'Pending' as opposed to 'Processed' status - using third party payment method (Mercado Pago)

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, order-status

**Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1**

Third party Module used: **Mercado Pago**
https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/plugins/official/magento-two

**Description:**
users are able to pay for orders and their payments are approved and authorised correctly.

However new orders are created as *'Pending'* and therefore a confirmation email is not sent.
If I go to the order *(Sales > Order > Order #00000)* I can change the status manually to *Processing* by invoicing the order, however **I would like to configure for new orders, with approved payments, to be created as processing.**

There is an option on the Module *(Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Method > Mercado Pago global Configuration)*, where we can define the status of new orders, which since installation has been selected as *'Processing'* but still new approved orders are created as 'Pending'.

**Please if anyone could help me on getting new orders to be created as Processing, that would be much appreciated.**

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have problems in

app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/State/RegisterCaptureNotificationCommand.php

```
public function execute(OrderPaymentInterface $payment, $amount, OrderInterface $order)
    {
      - $state = $order->getState() ?: Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
      + $state = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        $status = null;
        $message = 'Registered notification about captured amount of %1.';
```

This effects Paypal orders, however depending on how the module is written, it may affect your payment module.

Issue recorded on Github as MAGETWO-88244

Resolved in 2.4 (Apparently)

Comment: Thank you @elfling for the suggestion. I did the code change, new order is created and payment approved as usual, but unfortunately the status of the new order is still 'Pending'. I also read the issue you mentioned #88244 and although it worked for Paypal, annoyingly it did not work for this Payment module I am using, but thanks anyway.